# распарсить json в bash

Tags: bash, curl

как ***распарсить*** *json* в **bash** нативными методами без сторонних программ ?
и записать результат в переменную ?
я запускаю команду **curl**

```
curl -X GET "$HOST_NAME" -H $mail -H $key -H "$C_TYPE"
```

и получаю *json* ответ

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "id": "123",
      "name": "name"
    }
  ]
}
```

и мне нужно сохранить **123** в переменную

Comment: я бы сделал grep'ом, если вывод форматированный и всегда такой

Comment: Без сторонних программ в общем случае никак.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Именно для данного случая я бы сделал так:

```
eval `curl -X GET "$HOST_NAME" -H $mail -H $key -H "$C_TYPE"  | sed -r 's/"([a-z]+)":[ ]+("[a-z0-9]+")[,]{0,1}/\1=\2;/g;s/^[ \t]+//g' | grep ';'`
```

`Алгоритм довольно прост, ключ значение переводим к виду ключ="значние"; 
вместо "ключ": "значение", выбираем все строки где сработало регулярное выражение и объявляем полученные переменные.`

потом можно брать значения из переменных:

`# echo $id`

`123`

`# echo $name`

`name`

названием переменной будет ключ из json

**Важно**! решение довольно топорное и подойдет лишь для частных случаев.

проверял работоспособность так:

```
eval `echo -e '{\n  "result": [\n    {\n      "id": "123",\n      "name": "name"\n    }\n  ]\n}' | sed -r 's/"([a-z]+)":[ ]+("[a-z0-9]+")[,]{0,1}/\1=\2;/g;s/^[ \t]+//g' | grep ';'`
```

Comment: zOMG! Почитайте ответ @TotalPusher.

Comment: @0andriy Автор пишет:"без сторонних программ",  Total Pusher пишет: "есть программа jq, ее надо поставить". Вопрос, что от меня тебе нужно?

Comment: Ну автор не понимает, что в shell так нельзя. Вы, а не ты, ему просто потакаете.

Comment: @0andriy и что в этом плохого? Человек попросил о помощи, я ему помог, предупредил об осторожном использовании. Не нравится мой ответ, вы уже минус поставили, что доказать то теперь мне нужно? Если так хочется, можно по всем моим ответам пройтись и "заминусить", мне от этого ни горячо ни холодно. Хорошего вечера.

Comment: @PotroNik ну он наверняка знает почему нельзя, раз пишет что нельзя :), чувакам с микрофоном виднее

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я абсолютно не против этого)))) микрофон для того и нужен, что бы в него говорить, это я погорячился)))

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, спасибо, но это не обязательно)

Comment: Парсить json в оболочке очень и очень опасно и не разумно если есть `jq`

Answer (score 4):

Для парсинга есть программа [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/), но ее надо поставить (`sudo apt install jq` для Debian)

Тогда `id` можно получить так:

```
id=`curl -X GET "$HOST_NAME" -H "$mail" -H "$key" -H "$C_TYPE" | \
jq '.result[0].id | tonumber'`
```

Если id в виде строки, значение `"123"` с помощью `tonumber` превращается в `123`.

Answer (score 1):

я бы сделал grep'ом

https://rextester.com/ODSOK69881

```
ID=`echo "{
  "result": [
    {
      "id": "123",
      "name": "name"
    }
  ]
}" | grep id | tr ',' ' ' |  awk  '{print $2}'`

echo $ID
```